# ART equivalent of dvmDumpAllThreads

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug a native Android application using gdb on a newer device.
Is there an equivalent of `call dvmDumpAllThreads(true)` that I can call on an ART VM?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer for certain, but it's interesting problem so I searched a little bit. The stacktrace on [this](https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-store/issues/224) issue, combined with the information on [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash.html) page of the art documentation makes me think the answer is to call the [linux command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) (perhaps paired with [debuggrd](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/index.html))

```
abort(3);
```

or that an alternative might be to let it crash and look at a `Tombstone` report (outlined on the art documentation page I linked)

I don't generally like to make guesses, but as information seems to be scarce I thought I'd offer this. I'm sorry if it doesn't help!